# Frame Number in Reading .wav in Android

Tags: java, android, audio, wav, mfcc

I use [Reading Wav Files](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html) code in this link to read  .wav file (44100 sample rate) and got the data in double[frameNumber] buffer. but what makes me confuse is the size of the frame, why they set it to 100 for frame number to read?, and when i checked the total frame number for every different .wav that i've recorded, they have different number and the number is too big, i want to do mfcc from this buffer, should i use all the data in every frame to process it?

Comment: have you solved the problem? size of the frame has no meaning in case of PCM wav file.

Comment: @OakBytes i already solved it, and i use all the data, but to go to recognition i still confuse how to balance the data size

Comment: what do you mean by "balance the data size"?